# FaceBook stopped responding to my calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

When i try to connect to FaceBook, the app is moving to the Facebook app, and when it return to the my app, i get no response from FaceBook, and my app is not it Debug mode any more.
So i cannot use any loges to see whats going on.

This Never happened to me before, plus the app did work great with FaceBook until yesterday, something changed, and i do not no what, i really tried everything i could think of. 
including checking the bundel name again, checking FB ID, and checking i have the usual FaceBook methods Like :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];
    return YES;

    return NO;

}
```

And:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //Face boook sesstion:

    [[FBSession activeSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

The problem happen here:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"read_stream", @"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
```

//It never gets to here!!
//After the FaceBook returns to my app, i get no response at all!!

```
        if (status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
            [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *result, NSError *error) {

                NSString *fbID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [result objectForKey:@"first_name"], [result objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
                NSString *userName = fullName;
                NSString *email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
                NSString *phoneNumber = @"";
                NSString *userImageString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?height=400&type=normal&width=400", result.username];
                NSDictionary *fbDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[fbID, userName, fullName, email, phoneNumber, userImageString] forKeys:@[FB_ID, USER_USERNAME, USER_FULLNAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_PHONE,USER_IMAGE]];


                }];

            }];
```

I just can't understand how this is possible that there is no response at all, and because of that its so hard to figure out what is the problem...

Any help would be extremely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you have two apps with the same FacebookAppID installed on your device ?
In this case, it's possible that the second app is open instead of the one you're debugging.